# Is using the directory separator constant necessary?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am using PHP, but I *guess* this question might be language agnostic.

With PHP, a constant is defined by PHP, called `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. I have seen this in Joomla

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

I thought this looked like a good idea so I incorporated it into some of my sites. Now I'm asking myself why. I have only experience on Windows and OS X and from what I know Microsoft, Linux and Apple all use the forward slash as the directory separator.

Is using this constant unnecessary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mac OS Classic uses ":", for instance. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) for details. Also it's considered good style avoiding '[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constant)' or similar constructs.

Comment: Equating the use of '/' in pathing to a magic number requires some backing logic.

Answer (score 22):

As far as PHP is concerned, you might not need it when constructing a path, but it is important for anything you get from the OS.

From http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary:

> In attempting to write cross-platform, portable PHP code, I used PHP’s DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant to write path strings, e.g. `"..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."foo"`, because the “proper” way to do it on Windows would be `"..\foo"` while on everything else (Linux, UNIX, Mac OS X) it would be `"../foo"`.

> Well, as Christian on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php#73954) pointed out and the guys at Web Design Forums confirmed, that’s completely unnecessary. As long as you use the forward slash, “/”, you’ll be OK. Windows doesn’t mind it, and it’s best for *nix operating systems.

> (Note that `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is still useful for things like `explode`-ing a path that the *system* gave you. Thanks to Shadowfiend for pointing this out.)

Answer (score 6):

Windows actually uses a backslash as the directory separator, although some environments that have Windows versions will translate between forward slashes and backslashes automatically (Python comes to mind).

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure Windows will accept both and translate as necessary (I can CD to /Windows from the a cmd instance just fine).

Comment: @overslacked, partially you're right. cd D:/foo used to break, while cd /foo worked.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the best way to write cross-platform compatible code is to never use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, or backslashes `\\`, and to ONLY use forward slashes `/`.

Why? Because a backslash directory separator ONLY works on Windows. And forward slashes works on Linux, Windows, Mac altogether.

Using the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR or escaping your backslashes `\\` can become messy. Look at this example:

```
$file = 'path' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'to' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file';
$file = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'path/to/file';
$file = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? 'path\\to\\file' : 'path/to/file';
```

When you can just do this:

```
$file = 'path/to/file';
```

The only downside I came across is that PHP will return backslashes on Windows for all file references from functions like `realpath()`, `glob()`, and magic constants like `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`. So you might need to `str_replace()` them into forward slashes to keep it consistant.

```
$dir = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath('../'));
```

I am hoping that PHP in the future will introduce some php.ini setting to always return forward slashes.