# PHP site runs on linux but not on windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, path, require-once

I developed a website that runs perfectly on Linux, but when I try to run it on the Windows production server, the php script doesn't work. Everything that's in the code after this line doesn't do anything:

```
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'returner.php';
```

I thought that the proble could be related to the paths of the files, so I modified the code to use **DIR** and DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to avoid any kind of problems with the paths. I tested if the path was working using file_exists and the file was located, but my code still does nothing when I try to run it on the Windows server.

/index.php includes /lib/returner.php

/lib/returner.php includes /lib/login.php

Code:

index.php:

```
...
div class="container" role="main">
    <?php
        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'returner.php';
        echo '<div class="page-header">';
        echo '<h1>' . returnSede() . '</h1>';
        ...
```

returner.php:

```
...
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'login.php';
    $sede = $_POST['selectSede'];
...
```

Comment: windows have dir separator '\' and linux '/'

Comment: Turn on error reporting and read your logs.

Comment: @Eugen php will translate them if needed. I typically just use `/` and it works fine.. Also, OP is using the pre-defined constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR which should account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your code should work.

Just in case, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554966/756329) on Stack Overflow might shed some light. I'll kind of summarize:

If you're only worried about Unix-based or Windows, hard coding the path with forward slashes ("C:/test.txt") will work.

There can be discrepancies due to what type of quote you use:

- for instance, `"\123"` translates to `"Q"`
- Windows requires `"C:\\test.txt"` or `'C:\test.txt'` or `"C:/test.txt"`

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554847/756329) on the same question suggests doing something like this:

```
define('DS','/');
define('BASE_ROOT',str_replace('\\',DS,dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once BASE_ROOT . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'init.php';
```

Comment: using \__DIR__ has the same result than using dirname(\_\_FILE__) and my code isn't using any normal or backslashes, I'm using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to avoid having a mess with / and \ depending on the platform.

Comment: From the documentation linked in those other answers, it seems that using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR can have problems. The only counter-example I've read, however, was when using double quotes and DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR which can result in an unescaped backslash in double quotes which can give unexpected results. I'm curious to see what the actually fix for your situation is.