# How can I define the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for both Windows and Linux platforms?

Tags: php, windows, linux

Now I create a small PHP Application, here I have problem for using file path, because in Windows use this type location `C:\Some\Location\index` but in `Linux /www/app/index` so when I define the path using this `/` but when the application run in window machine it should be problem for this `/`.

So here I want to define the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR both Windows and Linux platform.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

PHP accepts both `\` and `/` as valid path separators in all OS. So just use `/` in your code

Comment: thanks a lot, last time i was always confuse for this / and \ .

Comment: not all os'es are windows and nix according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625332/is-using-the-directory-separator-constant-neccessary using it is more cross platform e.g. mac os classic uses : as separator. see also e.g. http://edward.de.leau.net/is-the-php-directory_separator-constant-really-needed-20130121.html

Comment: @edelwater: there is no reason to write your code according to requirements of unsupported 11yo OS. It's 2013 today. When you have something from nowadays - please welcome to discuss it. But referring to macos classic is just a nonsense

Comment: @zerkms so in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625332/is-using-the-directory-separator-constant-neccessary would not be the right answer? And ofcourse I understand that macos classic is old however are there NO current platforms where PHP is run that would fail? (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: @edelwater: I'm here not to judge right or wrong other people answers. I've given an answer based on my experience. As a developer I'm solving the real business issues, not imaginary. So could you please provide an example of a modern and supported OS in which my advice would fail? Without tons of links to wikipedia and/or other SO answers - just a name of the OS.

Comment: @zerkms Im looking for that also since im looking for the answer

Comment: @edelwater: well, there is no :-) It's safe to use just `/`

Comment: wrong statement! in Laravel i ve written `$user->photo()->create(['path'=>storage_path('rasmho/' . $filename ) ]);` and then used this path by gettinf to delete file and it just  ignores and now storage directory overfilled/ I ve traced the issue an it gives incorrect slash for windows os!

Comment: @CodeToLife in all php IO functions `\ ` and `/` act the same. If you used it for anything else - you obviously need to take into account requirements of the 3rd party tool. So it's not a "wrong statement", it's just you did not read it properly.

Answer (score 23):

For convenience you can write define a shorter constant:

```
DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and then write your path as:

```
$path = 'www'.DS.'app'.DS.'index';
```

Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: I wasted time by using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. After that "/" saves my time. Worked on Linux nicely but faced problem in windows.

Comment: `@Raju Ahmed` , on Laravel within Eloquents it doesnt work . I didnt get why it so. But after bringing out of eloquent say : `$sLcl=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR' and then usinj that variable it works ok now

Answer (score 7):

Please see [PHP Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Maybe it's already defined in your script, try echoing DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, see if it has any value

Answer (score 3):

PHP understands '\' and '/' as path separators, regardless on the system you're on. I prefer to use '/' (the unix way) in all of my code. When you're on a windows box and there is a need to provide a full qualified windows/DOS path I'll have this simple, non destructive function

```
function dosPath($path){
    return str_replace('/', '\\', $path);
}
```

Example:

```
$drive = 'C:';
$path = '/tmp/uploads';

echo dosPath($drive.$path);
echo dosPath($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows accepts forward slashes in most cases, so you can just use those. You can even use a mixture and it won't complain.

Make sure that your unit-test suite passes on Linux as well though!

Comment: Complain? It sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for window

```php
defined ('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

define( 'SITE_ROOT',  DS . 'xampp' . DS .'htdocs' .  DS .'gallery');
```

Comment: `defined ('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is messy, would you agree?

```
$file = 'path' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'to' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file';

$file = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'path/to/file';

$file = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? 'path\\to\\file' : 'path/to/file';
```

So just do this:

```
$file = 'path/to/file';
```

It works on Windows, Linux, Mac altogether. Backslash however only works on Windows and needs to be escaped `\\` so try to avoid them. :)

To turn a file referenced by PHP on Windows into forward slahes, use str_replace. Here is an example:

```
$dir = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath('../'));
```