# PHP require not work

Tags: php, windows, require, php-7, php-5.6

require function not work in windows10 with php7 ou 5.6 32 or 64 bits.

a.php

```
<?php
var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__.'/b.php'));
require __DIR__.'/b.php';
```

execution

```
C:\Users\diou_\OneDrive\www\coco>php a.php
bool(true)
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\diou_\OneDrive\www\coco/b.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in a.php on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\diou_\OneDrive\www\coco/b.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in a.php on line 4
```

Comment: Forward slash `(/)` is used as default in Linux while backward slash `(\)` is used in Windows & much more likely both slashes should work in Windows.

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619047/2298933

Comment: I tried with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, same error.

Comment: C:\Users\diou_\OneDrive\www\coco>c:\php\php.exe a.php
bool(true)
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\diou_\OneDrive\www\coco\b.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in a.php on line 4

Comment: Can you provide the content of a.php?

Comment: Sorry i meant b.php

Comment: b.php is <?php
echo "b\n";

Answer (score 1):

Maintain consistent directory separators.

You are switching between backslashes: `C:\Users\...` and forward slash: `/b.php`

So change `/b.php` to `\b.php`