# php does not detect subfolders and files

Tags: php

the php file and the folder are in the same directory, when I check the path that includes a subfolder and a file it shows that the file does not exist. but the path if it is in the windows explorer if it exists.

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');
if (!empty($_GET['copia']) ){
    $consultar1 = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM documentos" );
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($consultar1);
    if($total > 0){
        if (!file_exists("copia_seguridad")) {
                mkdir("copia_seguridad",0777,true);                 
            }
            
        while ( $doct = mysqli_fetch_row($consultar1)){
            $consultar_categoria = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombreCategoria FROM categorias");
            $subdirectory = mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_categoria);
            $longitud = count($subdirectory);
            for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++){
            $nombre_fichero = 'documentos/$subdirectory[$i]/".$doct[1].';
            if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
               echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero existe";
             } else {
               echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero no existe";
              }

            }
        }
        echo  "<script> alert('Copia de Seguridad realizada...'); </script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href = 'admin.php'; </script>";
    }else{
        echo  "<script> alert('No hay documentos para guardar...'); </script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href = 'admin.php'; </script>";
    }
}    
?>
```

[image: windows explorer path]

[image: error with "]

[image: error with ']

change the double quotes in the path to a single quote but it still doesn't detect the file.

How should the path be built for php to detect subfolders and files?

Comment: First you need to understand how to read error messages AND how single and double quotes work. Which, if you read your error messages, will tell you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: can you try `$nombre_fichero = "documentos/".$subdirectory[$i]."/".$doct[1];` ?

Comment: Also you should use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  constant to speed up lookup across Windows and Unix. You may have notice the slashes in different directions.  This can cause unexpected behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881333/when-to-use-directory-separator-in-php-code

Comment: Undefined offset occurs when I try to access an element of the array that does not exist, how do I save the result of a query in an array?

Comment: @IvesRodriguez Can you, just before the line  for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++){ - add in var_dump($doct); and var_dump($subdirectory); and var_dump($longitud);  and show the results for those.

Comment: just save one value https://i.imgur.com/xITSpjx.jpg, it should save five values https://i.imgur.com/AUyprMU.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```php
$nombre_fichero = 'documentos/$subdirectory[$i]/".$doct[1].';
```

to

```php
$nombre_fichero = 'documentos/' . $subdirectory[$i] . '/' . $doct[1].';
```

Also, try to avoid using other languages in variable "names".