# php can't find class

Tags: php, autoload

I try to run an php website on a raspberryPi (linux debian) in an apache docker container.
I use vs code with folowing extensions: 'PHP Debug' and 'PHP Intelephense'.

When I run the site on my windows pc te project works, when I try to run the site on te server I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "app\core\Request" not found in /var/www/test/core/Application.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/public/index.php(8): app\core\Application->__construct('/var/www/test_p...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/test/core/Application.php on line 19``

My map structur:

```
App
-Core
--Applicatoin.php
--Controller.php
--request.php
--response.php
--Router.php
-src
--controller
---HomeController.php
--models
--views
---home.php
-public
--index.php
```

The code it is refering to: 
(core/Applicatoin.php)

```php
<?php

namespace app\core;

use Dotenv\Loader\Resolver;

class Application
{
    public static string $ROOT_DIR;
    public Router $router;
    public Request $request;
    public Response $response;
    public static Application $app;

    public function __construct($rootPath)
    {
        self::$ROOT_DIR = $rootPath;
        self::$app = $this;
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->response = new Response();
        $this->router = new Router($this->request, $this->response);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo $this->router->resolve();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the new error?

Comment: P.S. You don't even need to suffer this problem at all, PHP already solved it. See [When to use DIRECTORY\_SEPARATOR in PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881333/when-to-use-directory-separator-in-php-code)

Comment: It might be spelling of files, rather. How do you set up the autoloader?

Comment: The new error is in the original post, ``Fatal error: Uncaugt Error: ...``.

Comment: `use` and `namespace` require backslashes; these have nothing to do with the local file-system.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive. Check upper/lowercase in Request, Response and Router classes.

Comment: Where is the `Request` class defined? Did you try to add a `\` in front of the classname?